NP-completeness and disjunctions
I have a question regarding NP-completeness and disjunctions.
Let $ A ⊆ N^2 $ be an NP-complete problem, and let $ a_1,...,a_n∈N $ be n (dstinct) fixed numbers.
Then, in general, can it be said whether the problem $B ⊆ N$ such that $ B(x):= A(x,a_1) ∨ A(x,a_2) ∨ ... ∨ A(x,a_n) $ is NP-complete?
If in general it is not NP-complete, are there some necessary and sufficient conditions where it is NP-complete?
Thank you very much.
P.S.
We may assume that $∀n∈N ∃x∈N s.t. A(x,n)$

The disjunction of two problems NP-complete is not necessarily NP-complete.
Take the example answer of 1.3 from these problems .
The problems of deciding $$A(x, 0) = \{1\#x : x \in SAT \} \cup \{0\#x : x \in \{0,1\}^∗\}$$ (deciding if the input string begins by $0$ OR if the input string begin
by one, and the remaining is a satisfiable boolean formula) is NP-complete. The same goes for $$A(x, 1) = \{0\#x : x \in SAT \} \cup \{1\#x : x \in \{0,1\}^∗\}$$
However, everything string will be satisfiable $A(x, 0) \lor A(x, 1)$ since it will be satisfiable if and only if it starts with either $0$ or $1$.

A sufficient condition for which $B(x)$ will be NP-complete is if we have $A(x, a) \subset A(x, b)$ if $a < b$, which is a very common condition (for example $k$-coloration, $k$-dominating set, $(n-k)$-clique...).
This is because $A(x,a_1) ∨ A(x,a_2) ∨ ... ∨ A(x,a_n) = A(x, \min_{i=1...n} x_i)$
This is a somewhat trivial result, but I doubt we can say much stronger things without more information...
